# Visual Studio 2015 - Creating Class at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

Will Visual Studio 2015 make it easy to create class at runtime and help to bring in dynamic code with ease?

Let me explain a little more on this. If I have a set of entities and attributes. Whats the best way to allow the user of the application to modify those entities and attributes OR Add new entities and attributes without touching the base code. Will Roslyn be the best candidate to accomplish this?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "create class at runtime"? Your question is too unclear to answer at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I am trying to allow the user to create the model class file dynamically and use it at runtime in the application.

Comment: So you really mean at runtime within the application, nothing to do with Visual Studio at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet Wandering if C# 6.0 and Roslyn give us something interesting in that and make this task easier.

Comment: C# 6 is mostly irrelevant I suspect - but Roslyn could be *very* relevant. Yes, if you include Roslyn as a dependency in your app you could generate and compile types at execution time more easily than before.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet . Do you have any good reference / suggestion for the same. I am sure, you must have some.

Comment: I'd just search for Roslyn tutorials - and read the documentation on the Roslyn github repo, too.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot

Comment: @JonSkeet I have elaborated the question with an example scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing *scripting*, and while it's one of Roslyn's intended scenarios, [the scripting APIs are still a work in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632984/how-do-i-enable-c-sharp-scripting-in-vs-2015). As @SLaks responds in this question, they've been removed from the release version of Roslyn but are available in the nightly builds.

If you google for "Roslyn scripting" you will find several tutorials, eg [this one](http://daveaglick.com/posts/compiler-platform-scripting).

The scripting APIs are already used by [scriptcs](https://github.com/scriptcs) to create a scripting environment for C#. scriptcs still requires a pre-release Roslyn version though, precisely because the scripting APIs were pulled from the release version

Answer (score -3):

Visual studio 2015 works quite well, I use it in my job for .NET projects.
It is quite simple with this language, to generate code dynamically, even classes. 
When you generate Classes, you have to generate it from somewhere :

- Model First : you create a schema and it generate the class from them with entity framework. Quite simple yet powerful
- Database First : You create tables inside database and it generates schema and Classes, less useful

I still deal with code first (Classes First) because I like to do it the hard way, more control over what I'm doing..

It surely depends on what language you want to work with but Visual Studio 2015 is a great tool for me

Comment: I don't think this is actually what the question is asking about.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am looking if I can even allow the user of my application to define the class within my compiled application.

Comment: The OP is asking about scripting, not code generation